# mailComposeViewController with pdf in PdfKit swift

Tags: swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, pdfkit

I have this code for one the pdf file  in Swift with PdfKit

but the the email don't open the in app I d'ont received any error

```
 let mailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
        if let lastPathComponent = pdfDocument?.documentURL?.lastPathComponent,
            let documentAttributes = pdfDocument?.documentAttributes,
            let attachmentData = pdfDocument?.dataRepresentation() {
            if let title = documentAttributes["Title"] as? String {
                mailComposeViewController.setSubject(title)
            }
            mailComposeViewController.addAttachmentData(attachmentData, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: lastPathComponent)
        }
```

Comment: try setting the mimeType to "public.composite-content" or "com.adobe.pdf"

Answer (score 0):

```
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    var documentsDirectory: String = paths[0]
    var finalPath: String = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("myPdf.pdf").absoluteString
    print("\(finalPath)")
    var error: Error? = nil
    var myData = Data(base64Encoded: pdfContent, options: [])
    var url = URL.fileURL(withPath: finalPath)
    if error != nil {
        print("Fail: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
    var mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {

        mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailComposer.addAttachmentData(myData!, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "myPdf.pdf")
        self.present(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: I add the delegate but I think the problems in presentation in last line of your code I received Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type '(() -> Void)?'

Comment: I tried in objc and just converted using convertor. Wait i will run and let u know

Comment: I use this code if you can run ,  the email part is not work not for pdf and If just add text is't run too 

https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/BookReader

Comment: Replace the line with self.present(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: if is possible can you give me your email for contact you in chat

Comment: give me ur id. I will ping

Comment: here is my id: 9335243 its so important to me for contacting with you in one chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165281/discussion-between-suganya-marlin-and-miloo).